# I want to print an Array ...Was Just checking for sorting but not able to print too?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*; 

class Sort {

   public static void main(String..s) {
      int a[]=new a[5];
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter 5 Numbers");
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
         a[i]=sc.nextInt();
      }
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
          System.out.println("Before Sorting"+ a[i]);
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: What sorting are you talking about?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to print"? Do you get some errors/exceptions or maybe unpredictable output? BTW you should start indenting your code. This helps you see scope better and prevents a lot of simple mistakes.

Comment: Are you using some online compiler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these utility functions:

- `java.util.Arrays.sort(...)`: Sorts the specified array
- `java.util.Arrays.toString(...)`: Returns a nicely formatted string representation of the array. Don't forget to print it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
int a[]=new a[5];
```

to

```
int a[]=new int[5];
```

Also change `String..s` to `String s[]` 
Please comment for further help.